# Dismiss Keyboard And Allow Button Gesture Recognizers Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using this code to hide the keyboard when the user taps anywhere on the screen outside of the TextView:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Looks for single or multiple taps.
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIInputViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.delegate = self
        //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    //Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.view is UIButton {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

The problem is I have a `UIButton` in this view as well - when I tap on the button, the button's gesture recognizer function is not called. Instead, `dismissKeyboard` is called. I already tried the suggestion of using  `tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false` as well as the `shouldReceive` method, but neither of them work - in the `shouldReceive` method, when I tap on the button, the class of `touch.view` is `UIView`.

Does anybody know how to allow the user to hide the keyboard when clicking anywhere on screen, but also allow button action handlers to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this using the following code:

1. I detect the location of the user's touch
2. I check if the touch is in the frame of each of the two buttons in my `UIView`
3. If this is true, I manually call the button handler and return false from the method

   ```
   public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if let view = self.view as? MyViewControllersView {
        let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
        if view.saveButton.frame.contains(location) {
            view.saveHit()
            return false
        } else if view.scanButton.frame.contains(location) {
            view.scanHit()
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me, please check out

```
//MARK:- View Lyfe cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnableAutoToolbar = false
//        IQKeyboardManager.shared().disabledToolbarClasses = self
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = false
    self.keyboardWillShowAndHide()
    initializeHideKeyboard()
 }

//MARK:- KayBoard Handling...
//MARK:- Init Hide KeyBoard...
func initializeHideKeyboard(){
    //Declare a Tap Gesture Recognizer which will trigger our dismissMyKeyboard() function
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
        target: self,
        action: #selector(dismissMyKeyboard))
    //Add this tap gesture recognizer to the parent view
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
//MARK:- Dismissing Keyboard...
@objc func dismissMyKeyboard(){
    //endEditing causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    //In short- Dismiss the active keyboard.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
//MARK:- Kayboard Hide and Show...
func keyboardWillShowAndHide(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow),
        name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil
    )
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(keyboarddidHide),
        name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil
    )
    
}
//MARK:- KeyBoard Will Show
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.arrConversationList.count
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        self.ChatBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight - self.bottomLayoutGuide.length
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.1, execute: {
            if  self.arrConversationList.count > 0 {
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.arrConversationList.count-1, section: 0)
                self.ConversationTblref.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
            }
        })
        self.tableviewbottomconstraintref.constant = 0
        ConversationTblref.reloadData()
    }
}
//MARK:- KeyBoard Will Hide
@objc func keyboarddidHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.tableviewbottomconstraintref.constant = 0
    self.ChatBottomConstraint.constant = 0
    ConversationTblref.reloadData()
}

//MARK:- View Disappear for handleing kayboard...
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnableAutoToolbar = true
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = true
     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    

}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   
}
```